# Smooth movement in different coordinate x y with gaped tick time

Tags: netlogo

Simplify the problem

Each agent has discrete tick-list,x-list,y-list.
for example, for agent 1
    t-list [1 5 10 15]
    x-list [2 3 4 5]
    y-list [6 7 8 9]
we want 
1,check if this agent has moved between current tick and next tick
2,if moved, fill the move path between the miss recored tick.
3,fill the path first then obstacle avoidance and crowds avoidance

The code is

```
to go
; check if updates are needed

ask turtles [

   let dex item 1 x-list - item 0 x-list
   let dey item 1 y-list - item 0 y-list

  if ( first t-list = ticks and dex = 0 and dey = 0 )  [
    ; update agent's location
    set xcor first x-list
    set ycor first y-list    
    set t-list but-first t-list
    set x-list but-first x-list
    set y-list but-first y-list
  ]
  if (ticks > first t-list and dex != 0 or dey != 0)[
    move-to patch-at (xcor + dex) (ycor + dey)
    ;; according to raw data, the interval of recorded t is fixed and equal to 12
    fd ( dex + dey ) / 12 
    set t-list but-first t-list
    set x-list but-first x-list
    set y-list but-first y-list 
    ]       
 pendown
 ]
 ; stop if lists for all agents are empty
 if all? turtles [ ticks > last t-list ] [
 stop
 ]
 tick 
 end
```

I need help after check dex ! = 0 and dry ! = 0, I want to make agent move step by step by (xcor + dex/det) (ycor + dry/det) at each tick first t-list + 1

Thank you for your kindly help!

Comment: I don't see any Java here.

Comment: Sorry, the package of A-star algorithm for path finding is written by Java and used as an extension in Netlogo. :)

Comment: It isn't doing you any good to have this question tagged java. People looking at the java tag aren't going to be able to help you with your netlogo program.

Comment: Thank you David, I removed the java tag 17 minutes ago. Thank you again!

Comment: Sorry, but I'm unable to understand your question. “how to fill the path and make it smooth” — what does it mean?

Comment: I readed the data and saved as four lists, tick-list, agentID-list,coordinateX-list and coordinateY-list. the tick time is a discrete series, such as 6, 12, 18 ...(only above tick time have recored agent ID and coordinate x,y). Since, the time interval may quite long, the coordinate x,y of current time and next time may quite distant. But agent move couldn't be jump in. Agent should move step by step during unrecorded tick time, (eg., sprout at tick time 6,and move smoothing in 7, 8, 9, 10,11 till arrived at cordite x, y at tick time 12)

Comment: Are you wondering how to interpolate between those points? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interpolation

Comment: interpolation, that could be one way, we may consider it when we want to complicate or improve the model later. For now, we just want to use the simple way first -- shortest path while can avoid obstacles like walls or other agents. sorry about my bad explanation.

Comment: Please edit your question to make it clearer, rather than tacking on comments. It might help if you showed a sample input and sample desired output.

Comment: thanks Seth, I finally make them move similar to what I want. this model still has a small error. And it still need to be improved. I want to upload a figure to show the running result. But I don't have enough reputation to upload it

Comment: So you solved it? If so, you should either answer the question yourself, or delete the question

Comment: not yet, for now agents can only move straightly or slanting, like I said, I want agents' move path similar to real human. Interpolation could be one good method, but I don't have any clue to solve it right now. Could anyone give me a hint? Thanks a lot